# Call method of a widget from another widget

Tags: flutter

I just started flutter, this is a basic question but I am not able to solve.
I created a stateful widget and I need to call the setState() method on click of a button. The button is not part of this stateful widget. The button is present in the footer of application.

complete application code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: "My app title",
        home: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("My App"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          ),
          body: new Container(
            child: new Center(
              child: new MyStateFullWidget(),
            ),
          ),
          persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // I need to call the update() of MyStateFullWidget/MyStateFullWidgetState class
              },
              child: new Text("Click Here"),
              color: Colors.amber,
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

class MyStateFullWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MyStateFullWidgetState();
  }
}

class MyStateFullWidgetState extends State<MyStateFullWidget> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Text("Count: $count");
  }

  update() {
    setState() {
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> I need to call the setState() method on click of a button

You may have a few options (or alternatives) to achieve the end result (all with different tradeoffs):

- Elevate the state (i.e. `count`) to an [Inherited Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) above the Button and Display Widget. This may be the easiest or most appropriate.
- Leverage some kind of Action-based communication such as [Flutter Redux](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux) (where you `dispatch` an action, which affects the display widget via a `StoreConnector` and rebuilds). This can be seen as just another way to 'elevate' state. However, this requires a whole new dependency and a lot of overhead given your simple example, but I wanted to point it out.
- You can create some kind of [Stream](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Stream-class.html) and [StreamController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) that the Display widget subscribes/listens to. However, this may be overkill and I'm not sure how appropriate representing button clicks over a stream would be.

There may be other solutions that I'm not thinking of; however, remember that the goal of reactive UI is to [keep state simple](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKXz3pUkw9A).

So if you have multiple leaf widgets that care about a piece of state (want to know it, want to change it), it might mean that this belongs to a higher level component (e.g a App-level piece of state, or maybe some other common ancestor - but both could use Inherited Widget to prevent passing the piece of state all around)

Comment: I achieved the purpose by using Inherited Widget

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you did this @Anil8753?

Comment: @MarkO'Sullivan I wrote a blog. http://www.hellomonk.com/2018/03/communication-between-widgets-using.html

Comment: Thank you @Anil8753! I would recommend creating a GitHub project showcasing this in case it stops working with a different version of Flutter / Dart

Comment: @Anil8753 , thanks for the code! btw I how do add input to it? for example if I wanna add another button/method for decrement?

Answer (score 0):

You should use your `Scaffold` in the `State` instead of using in `StatelessWidget`. 
Here is the working solution.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "My app title",
        home: MyStateFullWidget());
  }
}

class MyStateFullWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyStateFullWidgetState();
  }
}

class MyStateFullWidgetState extends State<MyStateFullWidget> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("My App"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child:Text("Count: $count"),
        ),
      ),
      persistentFooterButtons: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: update,
          child: Text("Click Here"),
          color: Colors.amber,
          textColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void update() {
    setState(() {
      count++;
    });
  }
}
```