# How to call function in a StatefulWidget from a button somewhere within another widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I call the `movePage(page)` function in `Widget1` from `MaterialButton` that placed deeply nested down below within the widget tree?

Please refer to example code below:

```
class Widget1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Widget1State createState() => _Widget1State();
}

class _Widget1State extends State<Widget1> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void movePage(page) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = page;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

///Somewhere nested down below within another widget in the widget tree
class Widget12 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(onPressed: () => {});
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information or code, what are you trying achieve

Comment: I want to call the setState() fucntion of a statefulWidget, when I press a button which is not placed within that widget.

Comment: You can use `Key`s, or an `InheritedWidget` (i.e. a [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)), check out this video to help you decide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: Hi @JacobPhillips, thanks for the comment. I had look some approach using provider but still trying to figuring it out, cause the provider needs build context as the parameter. Thanks for the references, will look at it when I'm free, and keep this posted.

Comment: @JacobPhillips the `InheritedWidget` works for me, thanks! however based on my research that using `Key` is not that recommended in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass it to the constructor. Try this on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter).

```
class Widget1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Widget1State createState() => _Widget1State();
}

class _Widget1State extends State<Widget1> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void movePage(int page) => setState(() => _selectedIndex += page);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('$_selectedIndex'),
        Widget2(func: movePage),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(int) func;

  const Widget2({Key key, @required this.func}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialButton(
      /// Try with any number.
      onPressed: () => func(2),
      child: Text('button'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Federick, thanks for your answer. The problem with this approach is, that Widget 2 mentioned above is nested deep down below in the widget tree. So passing through constructor will create a lot of boilerplate code in my case just only to do this one task. I was looking for some other approach using provider but still trying to figuring it out, cause the provider needs build context as the parameter.

Comment: I will also edit my post and the example code to clarify this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally find it working using `InheritedWidget`.

Reference:
[Call method of a widget from another widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432432/call-method-of-a-widget-from-another-widget)

The codes are in his blog:
http://www.hellomonk.com/2018/03/communication-between-widgets-using.html

I will just leave it here for who might need it as well.